# AngularJS accessing isolated scope in child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is my HTML part:

```
<div data-my-question="" data-question="Question text?">
    <div data-yes="">
        YES!
    </div>
    <div data-no="">
        NO!
    </div>
</div>
```

and here are my angular directives:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myQuestion', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                question: '@'
            },
            transclude: true,
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.answered = false;
                $scope.yesActive = false;

                $scope.activateYes = function (yesActive) {
                    $scope.answered = true;
                    $scope.yesActive = yesActive;
                };
            },
            template:  '<div>' +
                '<div class="question-box" ng-class="{answered: answered}">' +
                '<div class="question">' +
                '{{question}}' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="buttons">' +
                '<a href="" class="btn btn-small" ng-click="activateYes(true)">Yes</a>' +
                '<a href="" class="btn btn-small" ng-click="activateYes(false)">No</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>'
            };
    }
])
.directive('yes', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template:   '<p ng-show="answered && yesActive" ng-transclude></p>'
        };
    }
])
.directive('no', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template:   '<p ng-show="answered && !yesActive" ng-transclude></p>'
        };
    }
]);
```

The problem is, that the child directives ('yes', 'no') can't access the 'answered' and the 'yesActive' variable from the parent directive, which has an isolated scope.

How can I achieve that the child directives react on value changes from the parent directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transcluded elements won’t have access to the directive’s isolated scope.

This is how Angular works, an isolated scope (myQuestion) won’t inherit from any parent and the transcluded elements (Yes/No) will became siblings of the myQuestion’s scope.

Transcluded elements will be child of the original scope where they were defined, this way they are still able to bind instead of being isolated too.
[image]

If you check this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bekivaxi/1/edit), in the console you will see that Yes/No scope have access to the $rootScope (where pizza is defined) while myQuestion’s isolated scope won’t.

You can get more info about this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#understanding-how-scopes-work-with-transcluded-directives).

Solution:

I like simple code so I'd move the Yes/No elements inside the question template if possible, but you could also [communicate between directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate).

Comment: thx for the explanation. I solved the problem with broadcasting from question to YES/No